# Trying to remove a tuple using a prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm trying to use the user input to delete a tuple from the attribute song but I'm getting an error saying 
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Paragould' in 'where clause'`
Here is my code below

```
public static void removeSong(){
        Faker faker=new Faker();
        Statement stmt=null;
        Connection conn=null;

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which song would you like to remove?");
        String songName=in.next();
        String removeSongStmt="DELETE FROM allSavedSongs WHERE song="+songName+" AND userID="+currentUserID;
        try {
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt=conn.prepareStatement(removeSongStmt);
            preparedStmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You miss single quotes around song name

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 2):

The strings have to be in quotes, like this:

```
        String removeSongStmt="DELETE FROM allSavedSongs WHERE song='"+songName+"' AND userID='"+currentUserID+"';";
```

EDIT: This parsing is very unsafe because the string may contain any kind of rubbish. They might also contain SQL commands those would execute and harm you a lot. You should use the power of prepared statements, like this:

```
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt=conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM allSavedSongs WHERE song=? AND userID=?");
        preparedStmt.setString(songname);
        preparedStmt.setString(currentUserID);
        preparedStmt.execute();
```

Comment: String should be in **single** quotes like these `'`

Comment: Ah, thanks. However, the second variant should be prefered.